# Get data for last one year from database with whole month data

Tags: sql-server

I want to get data records for last one year which is ordered by date. But problem is that I need the data starting from first day of that month of past year.

For example, if its `15-June-2016` today, then I need to get data from `1-June-2015`.

I tried to do it with

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE
   date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
ORDER BY date
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Good. Next, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements, AND a desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first of the month of the previous year, use:

```
DATEADD(YEAR, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101'))
```

Your query should be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE 
    date > DATEADD(YEAR, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101'))
ORDER BY date
```

Reference:

- [Some Common Date Routines](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/lynnpettis/2009/03/25/some-common-date-routines/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE
    date >= DATEADD(YEAR,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()),0))
ORDER BY date
```

Comment: I think it should be `...date >= DATEADD(...` to include records from the 1st.

Comment: Exception - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from Table 
where date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) order by date asc;
```

Comment: NOW() isn't valid in SQL Server, perhaps you're thinking about getdate()?

Comment: @bender I need this thing for MySql too. But your solution is giving exactly for 1 year, not starting from first date. Please help further if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in you where condition.

Select * from Table where date > dateadd(year,-1,getdate())-day(getdate())+1 order by date

Thanks